# Teardown of injected types using Unity MVC bootstrapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container

I am using ***ASP.NET MVC WebApi 2*** and injecting concrete types into controllers using ***Unity 3*** and this [Unity MVC bootstrapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.AspNet.WebApi/3.0.1304).

The issue here is that one the registered types initialises an Entity Framework 6 `DbContext` for every resolve:

```
public sealed class EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    internal DbContext Context { get; private set; }

    public EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork()
    {
        Context = new SomeContext();
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (Context != null)
            {
                Context.Dispose();
                Context = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

For example, the `EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork` would be constructor injected into a controller like this:

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    public UsersController(IUserRepository userRepository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        // unitOfWork is a EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork
    }

    // ...
}
```

When the relevant ***MVC*** controller disposes, I need the `Dispose()` method to be called on the above `EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork` type, which in turn will dispose of the underlying `DbContext`.

Registering this type with Unity:

```
Container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork>(
    new DisposingTransientLifetimeManager()
);
```

I am using the `DisposingTransientLifetimeManager` lifetime manager, as suggested in [this article](http://thorarin.net/blog/post/2013/02/16/Unity-IoC-lifetime-management-IDisposable-part2.aspx), thinking that it would automatically dispose of my `IDisposable` types.  It seems that I still need to call on `Container.Teardown(someInstance)`.  This is not possible for me to do as the ***MVC Bootstrapper*** is handling all DI resolving.

**Where and how can I perform the teardown of these initialised types?**

It would be ideal to perform this teardown when the relevant MVC controller destructs, but perhaps this can also occur at the end of the HTTP request?

**EDIT:**

The IDisposables that are injected aren't necessarily accessible from the controller.  For example, I could also inject a `IUserService` into a controller which itself (the `IUserService` class) is injected with an `IUserRepository` and an `IUnitOfWork`.  I could chain Dispose methods from the `IUserService` to dispose of them, but this would requires changes to hundreds of controllers and services.  Ideally I should be able to call `container.Dispose()` somewhere to have Unity dispose all injected disposables.

**EDIT 2:**

RaraituL brought something else to mind.  `IUnitOfwork` does not implement `IDisposable`, only `EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork` does.  This essentially means that the an MVC controller wouldn't be able to call on a dispose method as it only knows of `IUnitOfWork`.  This is another reason why Unity should do this - it created the IDisposables so it should dispose of them too.

Comment: does `IUnitOfWork` implements `IDisposable`?

Comment: @RaraituL:  No.  That is actually a very good point.  An additional reason why Unity should do the disposing - only it should know which concrete types were resolved.

Comment: Original post updated.

Comment: I am using `Ninject` same way as you use `Unity`. And `Ninject` will dispose the references at the end of the request only if they implement `IDisposable`. Internally it checks something like `if(resource is IDisposable) { ((IDisposable)resource).Dispose() }. `Unity` doesn't detect that `IUnitOfWork` is disposable, so won't attempt to dispose it (unless it implements `IDisposable`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want a PerRequestTransientLifetimeManager.  That will be something you will have to build.  It's not hard and since you are using Unity 3 most of the work is already done for you.

```
public class PerRequestTransientLifetimeManager : ILifetimePolicy
{
    public object GetValue()
    {
        // will always create a new object (Transient)
        return null;
    }

    public void SetValue(object newValue)
    {
        // No point in saving to http context if not disposable
        if (newValue is IDisposable)
        {
            var perRequestLifetimeManager = new PerRequestLifetimeManager();
            perRequestLifetimeManager.SetValue(newValue);
        }
    }


    public void RemoveValue()
    {
        // can't remove since transient didn't keep a reference
    }
}
```

You'll need [Unity.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/3.5.1404) nuget package if the PerRequestLifetimeManager class is missing.  You'll also need to register the UnityPerRequestHttpModule using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule

I should point out from [MS site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.perrequestlifetimemanager%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx)

> Although the PerRequestLifetimeManager lifetime manager works
>   correctly and can help in working with stateful or thread-unsafe
>   dependencies within the scope of an HTTP request, it is generally not
>   a good idea to use it when it can be avoided, as it can often lead to
>   bad practices or hard to find bugs in the end-user's application code
>   when used incorrectly. It is recommended that the dependencies you
>   register are stateless and if there is a need to share common state
>   between several objects during the lifetime of an HTTP request, then
>   you can have a stateless service that explicitly stores and retrieves
>   this state using the Items collection of the Current object.

Comment: Thanks.  Would this essentially act exactly like the `TransientLifetimeManager` except that it will dispose registered `IDisposable` types?

Comment: Yes but it will dispose of anything that implements idisposable on the end of the http request that is registered with this lifetime manager.

Comment: @davenewza returning null from GetValue will tell Unity to always create a new object (aka transient) in the SetValue I just pass it on to the Unity PerRequestLifeTimeManager which will check if an object implements IDisposable and if so call the dispose method.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver` in the same NuGet package you already reference (Unity.AspNet.WebApi).  Then register your services you want disposed with the `HierarchicalLifetimeManager`.  This dependency resolver creates and disposes a new child container on every Web Api request.  When a Unity container is disposed, all built up objects in that container are also disposed.

```
IUnityContainer rootContainer = new UnityContainer();

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
    new UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver(rootContainer);

rootContainer.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork>
    (new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

Comment: Wouldn't the HierarchicallifetimeManager give OP the same object durning the request and not be transient? Same as a PreRequestLifetimeManager?

Comment: Yes it would. I did not see a requirement in OP's post for it to be transient.  In fact, EF would complain if you tred to join DbSets that were instantiated from different instances of a db context, so transient would be error prone.

Comment: This solution utilizes the same NuGet package that @davenewza already references with no custom classes. Just out-of-the-box behavior. :)

Comment: I'm not arguing with you :)  I just wanted to make sure it was doing what I thought it would do.  OP is currently using a Transient lifetimemanager.